# How to get a list of processes that explains Mapped in /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, memory-mapped-files, procfs

For example, I have:

```
 % grep '^Mapped:' /proc/meminfo
Mapped:           121868 kB
```

I want to generate something like this:

```
PID       Mapped        Path
123       1234 kB       /lib/libX.so
234       23445 kB      /bin/bash
...
TOTAL     121868 kB
```

So that, `TOTAL` is the same number from `/proc/meminfo`.
I looked thought `/proc/<pid>/smaps`, but not sure what exactly fields should I sum in order to get correct TOTAL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap). It should report the memory map of a process

Comment: It does report. pmap reads /proc/<pid>/maps and shows it in its own manner. But, how I can get a `Mapped:` number from `/proc/meminfo`?